# R: How to summarize categories?

Tags: r, categories

I have 60 categories (called CAT) of life forms (bears, tigers, whales, trees etc.) and I want to assign 10 summary categories (called THEME) to them.

```
> dt <- fread("lifeforms.csv")
> head(dt)
      CAT COUNT
1:  bears    10
2: tigers     3
3: whales     9
```

If it weren't so many I would simply use:

```
dt$THEME[dt$CAT=="tigers" | dt$CAT=="bears"]="Mammals"
```

But this takes too long and is too messy for my 60 different CAT values and 10 THEMEs. I have the "lookup" table in another data.table:

```
> catthemes <- fread("catthemes.csv")
> catthemes
      CAT   THEME
1:  bears Mammals
2: tigers Mammals
```

How to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(lifeforms, catthemes, by = 'CAT')
```

Comment: This works very well and it preserves the original row and column orders.

Answer (score 3):

```
CAT <- c("bears", "tigers", "whales", "lizards")
COUNT <- c(10, 3, 9, 15)
THEME <- c("Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Reptiles")

lifeforms <- data.frame(CAT, COUNT)
catthemes <- data.frame(CAT, THEME)


new_lifeforms <- merge(lifeforms, catthemes, by="CAT")

      CAT COUNT    THEME
1   bears    10  Mammals
2 lizards    15 Reptiles
3  tigers     3  Mammals
4  whales     9  Mammals
```

Comment: Suggestion: `all.x=TRUE`

Comment: It works well on a subset but with my whole dataset I get an error:
`Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 6771794 rows; more than 6733580 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.`